# Configuration file format with a schema?

Tags: configuration

I'm looking for a configuration file format with a schema. Something simple like YAML, but has a schema like XSD does for XML. Does this exist?

XML is a better serialization format than it is a configuration format but combined with XSD, it makes a powerful self-documenting configuration format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer is [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/). I recommend you read [Chapter 2](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/overview-of-config4star-syntax.html) (overview of the configuration syntax) and [Chapter 3](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/overview-of-the-config4star-api.html) (overview of the C++/Java API and overview of the schema language) of the *Config4* Getting Started Guide* to learn enough to decide if it suits your needs. Disclosure: I developed Config4*.

Another answer is Json, which now has its own [schema language](http://json-schema.org/). I haven't used it, so I can't comment on its merits.